# Executing same resource multiple times in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, infrastructure-as-code, terraform-template-file

I need to run a `local-exec` multiple times in my Terraform code.

```
resource "null_resource" "test_1" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "python test.py"
  }
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "test_2" {
  depends_on =[null_resource.test]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "python run.py"
  }

    triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }

}

resource "null_resource" "test_3" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.test_2]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "python test.py"
  }
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}
```

As we can see in the above code, `test_1` and `test_3` we are calling the same python file. But I need to explicitly call it. Is there any way to simplify? Like how we do in the imperative coding, where we call the like function.

As we all know the problem here, we need to write the same line of code multiple times and if there is a change, I need to make sure need to change it in all places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case with `python test.py` just use local variable:

```
locals {
    code_to_run = "python test.py"
}

resource "null_resource" "test_1" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = local.code_to_run
  }
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "test_2" {
  depends_on =[null_resource.test]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "python run.py"
  }

    triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }

}

resource "null_resource" "test_3" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.test_2]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = local.code_to_run
  }
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}
```

For more complex code, use [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) where you put code in **parametrized template**:

```
resource "null_resource" "test_1" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = templatefile("code_to_run.tmpl", {some_parmeter = "test_1"})
  }
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "test_2" {
  depends_on =[null_resource.test]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = templatefile("code_to_run.tmpl", {some_parmeter = "test_2"})
  }

    triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }

}

resource "null_resource" "test_3" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.test_2]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = templatefile("code_to_run.tmpl", {some_parmeter = "test_3"})
  }
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your response ! Yeah this will one way solve the issue . Is There any way, from 8 lines of recourse cod to 1 line? Like  call the `test_1` ..Just question

Comment: @Sreevathsabr You can create a module around your null resource. But this will not save much lines.

Comment: is there any possibility to put the sample . Sorry if I m asking for much !

Comment: @Sreevathsabr Not sure what sample? If this is new question, I would recommend actually new SO question with relevant details.